# How to convert activities to fragments to use in drawer

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, fragment, native

I am planning to convert the activities in my app to fragments to implement a drawer. But I have never used fragments before and they seem kinda complicated, so I'm asking for some quick help:

What are the basic "rules" to convert from activity to fragment?

All I have so far is that

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

becomes

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
```

What else? I guess I also have to change each layout from Linear/Relative to Fragment.

**EDIT**  I can't seem to figure it out properly. I have 3 activities:

A - base activity, no layout, starts service, threads, does a lot. Most back-end

B - extends A, has a layout. It's the main startup activity. Most front-end

C - extends A, has a layout. It's started via button from B.

Any suggestions on which and how to turn them to fragments?

Comment: check out this basic project setup I laid out, I think it makes seeing how Fragments work fairly clear: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default

Answer (score 1):

Have your fragment inherit from Fragment or an appropriate subclass.

Make sure your main activity has a DrawerLayout in the XML.  You can alternatively use

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction.Add
```

to add your drawer to the view.

Extra Reference:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I have already implemented the drawer in the main activity. My problem is converting the other activities into fragments to add them here

Comment: There should be minimal effort in converting activities to fragments because they are very similar.  Do you have a specific problem that I might be able to address?

Comment: Some simple instructions on how to convert, like "this turns to that", because I have absolutely no experience with Fragments so I don't know what I should change, what I should delete and what I should add instead

Comment: My advice for you is to just go ahead and convert it the best you can.   Don't let your inexperience roadblock you from experimenting and pioneering. There are very little changes between the two.  The main difference would be how you add it in your app whether it is through XML or through code.  

If you run into a problem you can't solve, let me know and I'll help you out.

Comment: when I change from extends Activity to extends Fragment, everything goes haywire. I have to put getActivity() everywhere right? (and replace all "this" with getActivity())

Comment: Store the Activity as a class variable instead of calling it multiple times but that is the way to go.

Comment: please see my edit, cause I'm really lost. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's keep it simple then.  Let's say I have ListFragment that I want to put in my activity.  One way I would add it would be to:

- add a frame_layout to the xml and with the layout settings and id it "@id+/example_list"
- in onCreate of the activity, add the code

  ```
  CustomListFragmentClass myCustomListFragmentClass;
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.example_list, myCustomListFragmentClass, "listFrag").commit();
  ```

The fragment should now be visible.

Comment: I have no idea what this means :) Is this related to my edit? Cause those 3 classes are not hypothetical, I really have them like that and I don't know how and which one to turn to fragment